# Build app for iphone but not for ipad (Sencha Touch)

Tags: iphone, ipad, sencha-touch

I need build my app on Iphone and Ipad, but I want to keep Iphone's resolution, I mean.. I want to see my app on ipad like 1x / 2x

like this:
http://blog.m4n.nl/wp-content/uploads/m4n_on_ipad-787x1024.jpg

Help me please :)
Thank You

Comment: You don't need to. When you create new project just select iPHone and leave rest to UIKit framework. Universal apps need additional functionality. this is default behavior. Please do some research or try something before asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you change 'Devices' in project settings to 'iPhone' instead of 'universal', it should work as u want to.

[image: Project Settings]

Answer (score 0):

So what the big issue?? Just choose `Devices` to `iPhone` and create your project. Start coding and just run it on iPad. You could see that `Xcode` did the same that you want.
[image]